# Need counter examples to remove options for sequence questions

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was doing assignment having multiple choice questions . To remove options i need counter examples . i have tried few but they doesnt seem to work

P1 : Let  be a sequence such that lim as n goes to infinity ($a_{n+1}$ - $a_n$) = L .Then the sequence $b_n$= $a_n$/n

OPTIONS : -

A) Converges to 0

B) May or maynot converge

c) Converge to L

d) Bounded but may not converge

Atempt : If i take $a_n$=$1/n$  .Then i see my d option is removed and might be b) also .But to remove between  a) and c) im stuck how to do .As in many examples a and c become same

Anyhelp would be appreciated

Comment: @bof Hi thanks for answer .My apologies .$a_n$ = n rules out every three options other than c .Isnt't it :Thanks .pls post as an answer so that i may upvote you

Comment: @bof u indicate cauchy 1st theorem on limits of sequence !

Comment: @bof yes $a_n$=n and cauchy first theorem on limits will advocate c in all aspects

Comment: @bof if we take $d_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$ then $d_1$ + $d_2$ ...$d_n$ = $a_n$ - $a_1$ ...because of cancellation of other $a_n$ terms but $a_1$ remains .how to deal with that

Comment: I said $d_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$ for $n\gt1$ but $d_1=a_1$; so $d_1+d_2=a_1+(a_2-a_1)=a_2$, and $d_1+d_2+d_3=a_3$, etc.; $d_n$ is defined so that $d_1+d_2+\cdots+d_n=a_n$ for every positive integer $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $d_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$ for $n\gt1$, and let $d_1=a_1$; then $d_n\to L$ as $n\to\infty$, and
$$b_n=\frac{a_n}n=\frac{d_1+\cdots+d_n}n$$
so $b_n\to L$ by Cauchy's "first theorem on limits". This shows that c) is true, while b) and d) are false because $b_n$ necessarily converges. To rule out a) consider an example where $L\ne0$, e.g., $a_n=n,\,L=1,\,b_n=1$.